# Displaying Associated Objects in Rails Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails 4 application that currently has two models User and Status.  In the user model I defined the association below.  Both the status and user tables are populating with information.  Statuses are loading with an associated user_id

**User Model**

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I have the following block in my show status view which will display the user_id and and the content of the status

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
   <div class="status">
   <strong> <%=status.user_id%></strong>
   <p> <%=status.content%></p>
```

I would like to display the user's first name instead.  According the tutorial i'm taking I should be able to use this code since I have the association defined however it's returning the error below.

```
  <%=@status.user.first_name%> 

  Error      
  #==>undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I display first_name in the controller?   Do I need to define a new method for user or should the association provide?

**Relevant Controller Code for Reference**

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController


  before_action :set_status,:set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json

 def index
    @statuses = Status.all
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json

  def show
    puts "debug msg #{@status.inspect}"
  end



  # GET /statuses/new
  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json

...
...
...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:id])
      puts "in set status"
    end

    def set_user
      @status.user = User.find_by(@status.user_id)
    end



    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sees like there is no problem in your code. The error `undefined method first_name for nil:NilClass` means that the `status` object not associated with `user` or `user` have no field `first_name`. Try following code:

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
   <div class="status">
   <strong> <%=status.user.try(:first_name) %></strong>
   <p> <%=status.content%></p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The page no longer displays an error but still no first name either.   I'm not familiar with that method what does "try" do?

Comment: It will return empty value if there is no method `first_name` for NilClass, [here docs](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try). And try to inspect user object like this: `status.user.inspect`, if it return nil you have no association with user.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  I figured out it was a data issue I have been assuming it was an issue with my controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what page you are trying to display `<%=@status.user.first_name%>` this on, but this should work.

You can use the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) gem:

```
def show
  @statuses = @statuses.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

add this to the view:

```
<%= will_paginate %>
```

or this should be the normal way:

```
def show
  @statuses = @statuses.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to return the Status index page which list all statuses by any user.   So @statuses is a hash of the user statuses which includes user_id I just want to convert the user_id for each status to the first name.

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer but this should display all of the statuses.